# Faster way of iterating through lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

I have list vector_list of length 800,000, where the elements are lists of size 768. I'm trying to add 768 columns to a pandas dataframe where each column is 800,000 long and represents an element from each list. Here's my code:

```
active = pd.DataFrame()    
for i in range(len(vector_list[0])):
    element_list = []
    for j in range(len(vector_list)):
        element_list.append(vector_list[j][i])
    active['Element {}'.format(i)] = element_list
```

Just to reiterate,

```
len(vector_list) = 800,000
len(vector_list[0]) = 768
```

Is there a more clever, faster way to do this?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(vector_list)` ?

Comment: Pass your vector list to the pd.DataFrame constructor and use the names parameter and insert it the names of the columns ?

Comment: Yep that's all I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Directly pass the `list` to `DataFrame` constructor.

```py
import pandas as pd
_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(_list) 
print(df.head())
```

Output

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8
```